# What happens if changing country I don't unregister from the first country health insurance system?

Tags: eu, health-insurance

Refer to what this user is saying [here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/66/is-there-any-advantages-in-changing-the-%20residence-when-changing-country-in-eu?noredirect=1#comment73_66):

> Remember that no matter what, if you stop working in country X and start working in country Y (both in EU), you have to unregister from health insurance in X and register in Y.

What are the consequences if I don't inform my old country (Italy) that I've moved to another country (Austria) for work?

Comment: Please, explain me the close vote so that I can improve my question.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but the 'Too Broad' vote might be related to the fact that it doesn't mention which country you've moved from/to... which might be relevant to the answer.

Comment: @Flimzy It might be relevant, but health insurance is quite strongly EU-regulated, so most things apply EU-wide.

Comment: @Flimzy: I think the EU criteria does limit the questions scope enough to be on-topic

Comment: @SztupY: Anyway, I've added the name of the two countries

Comment: @SztupY: Like I said, I didn't vote to close... and I don't know EU law/politics/etc enough to make a determination. I'm just offering my best guess for the VtC... but it's only 1 of 5.  So don't fret it yet :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the European Union, there are strict regulations considering health insurance:

1. You have to be health insured (remember that in unemployment stage, most governments pay your basic health insurance).
2. If you are employed in any country, you have to be insured in such country. If you are employed in more, you can choose any of them.

However, the regulations don't say what to do if the new country is unable to register you instantly. In France the registration takes up to several months. Most people choose to pay the minimal insurance in their original country until the French administration proceeds their file. However, this is officially illegal.

As far as I know, the countries don't imply any fines if you break the rules, but the health insurance companies can probably void the insurance if they find out you break the rules.

**Example 1:** You are a 27-year-old PhD student in Czechia and you come to study in France for an exchange program for which you obtain a "bourse du gouvernement français" which is not a work contract. You can choose any of these two countries (and theoretically any other country as well) for your health insurance. In the Czech Republic, as a student 26+ you pay circa EUR 40 a month for that.

**Example 2:** You graduate your masters in the Czech Republic and you get a PhD contract in France. As long as you don't work in the Czech Republic, you have to re-register in France, since work contract is a work contract, even if you're also a student.

(Example 1 is actually my situation, Example 2 is the situation of my good friend.)

Comment: As far as I know in Italy we don't have any insurance.. The health system is for free for everyone. Another good question could be about the difference in the health system of the various countries.

Comment: I really like this answer, as it wraps it up pretty nicely. Indeed, the EU is pretty strict about it (and their information exchange in such cases works better than one would expect).

Comment: @e-sushi: are you sure about that? I guess in Italy no one is going to check.. :p

Comment: @Revious Are you sure it's _free_? In Czechia, the Netherlands and many other countries it is _governmental_, and is (moreorless) collected with the income tax.

Comment: @tohecz: I don't know.. but in Italy no one speaks of sanitary *insurance*. For sure it's something that is payed for italian people but I don't know if you have to be resident :-(

Comment: @tohecz Of course it's never free as such, *free* in this context means 100% financed through taxes.  Oh, and I'm pretty sure it's not collected with income tax in The Netherlands.

Comment: (+1) The usual way to put it is “free at the point of use”. In the Netherlands, people have to pay a private insurer but this is far from covering all the costs so there is a income-tax-like contribution (*bijdrage Zorgverzerkeringswet*). Note that it's possible to have a healthcare system that is not mainly based on insurance (i.e. the NHS).