# Can I register a Nebenwohnung before I have a Hauptwohnung?

Tags: germany, residency

Suppose that married persons X and Y are moving to Germany.  They will share a *Hauptwohnung* (primary residence) in city A, but X will additionally occupy a *Nebenwohnung* (secondary residence) in city B because X has a job at the other end of the country.  So far so good: both will register as *Hauptwohnung* in city A, and X will additionally register as *Nebenwohnung* in city B.

However, due to timing reasons, X is moving to Germany before Y does, and will live primarily in what will be the *Nebenwohnung* for the first 6 weeks or so.  Can X register their residency in city B as *Nebenwohnung*, *before* X and Y together register their residency in city A as *Hauptwohnung*?  Or must X initially register residency as city B as *Hauptwohnung*, and then re-register in city B as *Nebenwohnung* as soon as Y moves to Germany and both partners register together in city A as *Hauptwohnnung*?

The registration form ([example from Offenbach](https://www.offenbach.de/vv/Anmeldung.pdf), but I expect it's the same elsewhere) appears not to ask people registering a *Nebenwohnung*, what their *Hauptwohnung* is, although it does ask for address details for the Ehegatte (partner).

Answer (score 1):

German residence registers only care about residences in Germany. You can’t have a secondary residence if you don’t have a primary residence (in Germany).

Therefore, X will need to register in B as their *only residence* (treated the same as a primary residence), and later X and Y will register their shared primary residence in A. Downgrading the residence in B isn’t a separate step, it will be done registering in A.

Comment: *You can’t have a secondary residence if you don’t have a primary residence (in Germany).*, that directly contradicts the other answer.  Do you have a source backing up that one cannot?

Comment: @gerrit: I can refer to the law (in German only, of course), [§ 21 BMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bmg/__21.html). Note how it always speaks about residences “im Inland”, i.e. in Germany.

Comment: It says *Hat ein Einwohner mehrere Wohnungen im Inland, so ist eine dieser Wohnungen seine Hauptwohnung.*, but in the case described in the question, the Einwohner hat nur eine Wohnung im Inland, nicht mehrere...

Comment: I'm just worried about the tax consequences if, for six weeks, we would have different Hauptwohnung despite being married, which may lead the authorities to conclude that we live separated.

Comment: @gerrit: Separation requires intent (“… wenn zwischen ihnen keine häusliche Gemeinschaft besteht **und** ein Ehegatte sie erkennbar nicht herstellen will, weil er die eheliche Lebensgemeinschaft ablehnt”, [§ 1567 BGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__1567.html)). Regarding the other comment: As I say in my answer, it is technically not a _primary residence_ but the _only residence_ (_alleinige Wohnung_), but treated the same. See, e.g., the final part of § 21 BMG (“… die für die alleinige Wohnung oder die Hauptwohnung zuständig ist“).

Comment: Sadly, I think this is the correct answer.  One can't have a more definitive answer than the actual law.  Chirlu: could you [edit] the link directly into your answer - ideally answers should be self-standing, not dependant on the comment.  I have deleted my answer.