# Will failure to deregister from Germany cause problems registering 11 years later?

Tags: germany, residency, arrival, departure

I am a Dutch citizen and I was living in Germany for 6 months 2007–2008 for the purpose of studying.  I'm quite sure that I registered as living there at the time, for I had a bank account and I voted in the [local elections](https://wuerzburgwiki.de/wiki/Kommunalwahl_2008#OB-Wahl).  I don't remember deregistering when I moved to Sweden.  I am now about to move back to Germany.  Should I expect problems in case I indeed failed to deregister in 2008?

Comment: Why the downvote?